# Can Anyone give me a solution to my subquery in the from clause?

Tags: sql

I have to write a query using a subquery within the from clause to get the top 5 customers based on number of orders. The outer query should display the customer id,date of first order,date of last order, and total orders received. 
The problem that i am having is that in my subquery where i have dbo.Customers.orderid Im getting an error saying the multi part identifier can not be bound. What am i missing in my query? Can someone help thanks

here is the query i tried

```
SELECT        CustomerID, MAX(OrderDate) AS LastOrder, MIN(OrderDate) AS FirstOrder, COUNT(OrderID) AS [TotalOrders]
FROM            dbo.Orders join

            ( SELECT        Top 5 CustomerID As TopCustomer
              FROM            dbo.customers
             group by customerid 
             order by  TopCustomer desc) As TopCustomer
              ON dbo.Customers.orderid = dbo.Orders.CustomerID
```

Comment: your subquery is aliased as `TopCustomer`, but you're joining on `dbo.Customers`, which doesn't exist anywhere in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the same query with use of aliases in order to avoid such kind of errors:

```
SELECT O.CustomerID
   , MAX(OrderDate) AS LastOrder
   , MIN(OrderDate) AS FirstOrder
   , COUNT(OrderID) AS TotalOrders
FROM dbo.Orders AS O
JOIN (SELECT Top 5 C.CustomerID AS TopCustomerID
      FROM dbo.customers AS C
      GROUP BY C.CustomerID 
      ORDER BY C.CustomerID DESC) AS TC ON TC.TopCustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY O.CustomerID
```

I also added a `GROUP BY` clause in your main query, that's required if you want to use functions like `MAX`, `MIN`...

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time out to help and @Joël Salamin this solution worked perfectly thanks

Comment: You're welcome. As a best practice, try to always use aliases in your queries in order to avoid such kind of errors. It's also easier to read when you use pertinent aliases.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        CustomerID, 
              MAX(OrderDate) AS LastOrder, 
              MIN(OrderDate) AS FirstOrder, 
              COUNT(OrderID) AS [TotalOrders]
FROM          dbo.Orders join

            ( SELECT  Top 5 CustomerID As TopCustomerId
                      FROM  dbo.customers
                      group by CustomerID
                      order by  CustomerID desc
            ) As TopCustomer
             ON TopCustomer.TopCustomerId= dbo.Orders.CustomerID
```

Comment: when i try this way i get an error that the multipart identifier  topcustomer.topcustomer id could not be bound

Comment: @karodhill see me edited answer and let me know is it working or not

Comment: thank you @ Khurram Ali I had to change the alias I had I dont know why it didnt like it but thank you for helping